# R Shiny, fileInput displays "Upload Completed" a few seconds before it is actually done

Tags: r, shiny

I typically need to upload large (~700MB) csv files into my shiny app. The problem is, it shows "Upload Completed" in less than 3 seconds or so, while it actually takes around 20 seconds (have also confirmed it by printing some rows of the data).

Is there a workaround for this?

```
ui <- fluidPage( 

  titlePanel("Predictive Models"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv"),
                width = "80%")
       ...
server <- function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL, station_id= NULL, station_name= NULL, station_data=NULL, processed_data=NULL,df=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    values$df_data <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath);

    output$sum <- renderPrint({
      print(head(values$df_data, 10))
    }) 
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 steps to uploading a file.

1. The file is placed into a temp folder defined by tempdir()
2. The file is read into memory using read.csv()

The upload bar we see with fileInput only measures the time to upload the file to the server and into the temp directory. Not the time to read it into memory.

Since `read.csv()` blocks the server till the operation is completed, the only way to measure the time to read the file into memory would be to read the file in batches. In each step, we log the progress using `Progress`.

Here is a sample, it is not the most efficient code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 

  titlePanel("Predictive Models"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv"),
                width = "80%")
    ),
    mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("sum"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=800*1024^2) 

  read_batch_with_progress = function(file_path,nrows,no_batches){
    progress = Progress$new(session, min = 1,max = no_batches)
    progress$set(message = "Reading ...")
    seq_length = ceiling(seq.int(from = 2, to = nrows-2,length.out = no_batches+1))
    seq_length = seq_length[-length(seq_length)]

    #read the first line
    df = read.csv(file_path,skip = 0,nrows = 1)
    col_names = colnames(df)

    for(i in seq_along(seq_length)){
      progress$set(value = i)
      if(i == no_batches) chunk_size = -1 else chunk_size = seq_length[i+1] - seq_length[i]

      df_temp = read.csv(file_path, skip = seq_length[i], nrows = chunk_size,header = FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      colnames(df_temp) = col_names
      df = rbind(df,df_temp)
    }

    progress$close()
    return(df)
  }


  df = reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    n_rows = length(count.fields(input$file1$datapath))

    df_out = read_batch_with_progress(input$file1$datapath,n_rows,10)

    return(df_out)
  })

  observe({
    output$sum <- renderPrint({
      print(head(df(), 10))
    }) 
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This code splits the file into 10 chunks and reads each chunk into memory, appending it to the previous chunk. In each step, it logs the progress using `progress$set(value = i)`

Comment: Thanks! It still is a bit awkward for the user, since one says "upload complete" while another progress bar keeps track of the process. But it's definitely better than before :)

Comment: @Alex I agree. This solution mainly explains why the issue occurs and it is a hacky solution. Fancier solutions are probably possible through custom javascript code.